# How many paths do the default search paths introduced in the fontspec package contain?

Tags: fontspec

[image]

This is an extract from the fontspec package. I want to know for mac the default search paths contain what?

Comment: Open a terminal and type `kpsepath tex` and look for the ones ending in `latex`: or for slightly more user friendly output: `kpsepath tex | sed -e 's/:/\n/g' -e 's/!!//g' -e 's:/\+:/:g' | grep latex\/$`. You can use subfolders of those folders.

Comment: You can probably use the same folders with `tex/latex` at the end replaced with `fonts/opentype`, `fonts/truetype` and similar. This really should be better documented, actually.

Comment: Looks like `kpsewhich -show-path .otf` and `kpsewhich -show-path .ttf` show those folders, but the `kpsepath tex` ones work as well from my testing.